# SQL: How to delete all items in a group if one matches a condition?

Tags: sql, group-by, conditional-statements

I am hoping to create a function that can delete all items in a group if any one of them matches a specific condition.

Specifically, I have a dataset 'family' and I want to delete all members of the family if that family contains twins.

A portion of the dataset looks like this:

| Subject ID | Mother_ID | Zygosity_SR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2001 | MZ |
| 1002 | 2001 | MZ |
| 1003 | 2001 | NotTwin |
| 1004 | 2002 | NotTwin |
| 1005 | 2002 | NotTwin |

In this case I want to delete all rows with individuals with the same Mother_ID as the Subjects with Zygosity_SR = MZ.

My resulting table would look like this:

| Subject ID | Mother_ID | Zygosity_SR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1004 | 2002 | NotTwin |
| 1005 | 2002 | NotTwin |

This is the SQL code I have so far, but I could really use some guidance on where to go from here:

```
proc sql; 
delete from family 
where ZygositySR = 'MZ'
group by Mother ID
;
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `exists`:

```
delete from family 
    where exists (select 1
                  from family f2
                  where f2.mother_id = family.mother_id and
                        f2.ZygositySR = 'MZ'
                 );
```

Comment: When I run that code it deletes all of the subjects in the dataset, do you have any tips on how to fix this? I'm also getting an error:  This DELETE/INSERT statement recursively references the target table. A consequence of this is a possible data integrity problem"
Thank you so much

Comment: @Randy . . . This is odd behavior.  This is standard SQL -- so I could understand how it might not run (some feature not supported) but not how it could do anything else.  You might need to create a temporary dataset to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If `exists` is not working how about the alternative `in` method

```
delete from family
where mother_Id in (select Mother_Id from family where zygosity_SR='MZ')
```

Comment: This correctly deleted the 'MZ' twins but not their "NotTwin" siblings.. do you think I need to replace "Mother_ID" in one of those locations to delete the MZ twin and their siblings? Thank you so much

Comment: @Randymaybe it's as simple as this - have edited to a simpler query without any correlation, I think that's what you want.